# How to add a back button to go back to previous page

Tags: python, webkit

I'm currently new to Ubuntu programming, and learning the basic's of it. I've been following this tutorial as some of you might know in previous questions asked about it I've made before.

Now, I've created a Web browser using 'quickly'. It's a simple program witch helps create programs on Ubuntu.  In the video It showed how to 'refresh' the page witch is basically this code:

```
def on_refreshbutton_clicked(self, widget):
    self.webview.reload()
```

Now, my question is to make the page go back from a previous page is it this code:

```
def on_refreshbutton_clicked(self, widget):
    self.webview.back()
```

I used 'refreshbutton' as a example, but if you would like to view the full source of the  the code just ask for it and I'll provide you with a link witch you can view the source.

Comment: @minerz029: I would highly discourage that method. First because the `WebkitWebView` has specialised methods to handle this and second you'll need to have a better implementation than you suggest. Remmoving urls when going back etc.

Answer (score 0):

The `WebkitWebView` has a [`go_back()`](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/webkitgtk-webkitwebview.html#webkit-web-view-go-back) and [`go_forward()`](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/webkitgtk-webkitwebview.html#webkit-web-view-go-forward) method which will handle everything for you. So going from your example, just do:

```
def on_backbutton_clicked(self, widget):
    self.webview.go_back()

def on_forwardbutton_clicked(self, widget):
    self.webview.go_forward()
```

Comment: Hi, to forward your question. Would I need to add the following:

self.backbutton = self.builder.get_object("backbutton")
self.forwardbutton = self.builder.get_object("forwardbutton")

Comment: @Shaun: No, not if you don't want to use those in your code. The snippet above only requires you to connect the `clicked` signals of those buttons.